# Confusion about setting column width in huxtable

Tags: r, pdf, cpu-word, column-width

I am a little bit confused about how setting column widths works for tables in the R package `huxtable`. The documentation says that in the call to `set_col_width` the argument `value`, if numeric, specifies column widths as proportions of the overall width (which is set by `set_width`). But, when I write a table to Word, a numeric vector for `value` seems to instead specify absolute column width (which I actually like), apparently in inches, regardless of the value set in `set_width`. For pdf output, column width specifications don't seem to have any effect at all.

Consider the following example.

```
library(dplyr)
library(huxtable)

test=data.frame(var1=1918:1925,var2=c(9009,1000:1006),var3 = 1100:1107)
HUX <- hux(test)

# add caption, borders, and colnames
HUX <- set_caption(HUX,"Example table") %>%
set_caption_pos("topleft") %>%
set_top_border(1,,1) %>%
set_bottom_border(final(1), , 1)    %>%
set_align(,,"left") %>%
add_colnames()
number_format(HUX)[,2:3] <- list(function(x) prettyNum(x, big.mark=","))
```

If I set column widths, they are reflected in the Word output, but not the pdf output, but apparently as absolute, not proportional widths.

```
HUX <- set_width(HUX,1) %>%
    set_col_width(1:3, c(2,1,1))
quick_docx(HUX)  
quick_pdf(HUX)                                

file.remove(c("huxtable-output.pdf","huxtable-output.docx"))
HUX <- set_width(HUX,1) %>%
    set_col_width(1:3, c(2,3,1))
quick_docx(HUX)  
quick_pdf(HUX)
```

The above code changes the column widths (and the overall table widths, even though the width set in `set_width` is unchanged), but only in Word, not for the pdf output. Changing the argument in `set_with` has no effect in Word, but does shift the table in the pdf (although the appearance of the table itself is unchanged), presumably because the "table plotting area" is smaller, and the edge is thus shifted, and the position of the table is left-justified in this "area".

```
file.remove(c("huxtable-output.pdf","huxtable-output.docx"))
HUX <- set_width(HUX,0.5) %>%
    set_col_width(1:3, c(2,3,1))
quick_docx(HUX)  
quick_pdf(HUX)
```

Now, when I try to specify column width using valid (I think) LaTex lengths, it makes no difference for the pdf, and neither does it actually set column widths for the Word output.

```
file.remove(c("huxtable-output.pdf","huxtable-output.docx"))
HUX <- set_width(HUX,1) %>%
    set_col_width(1:3, paste0(c(2,3,1),"in"))
quick_docx(HUX)  
quick_pdf(HUX)
```

Moreover, now, having tried LaTex length specifications, the previous code (above) that *did* successfully set column widths for the Word output, no longer does so.

```
file.remove(c("huxtable-output.pdf","huxtable-output.docx"))
HUX <- set_width(HUX,1) %>%
    set_col_width(1:3, c(2,3,1))
quick_docx(HUX)  
quick_pdf(HUX)
```

I apologize if I'm missing something obvious here, but I just can't seem to get this column width specification working the way I expected. Many thanks to anyone who can clear this up for me.

The bottom line is that I'd like to be able to explicitly set column widths, regardless of the cell contents of a table (i.e., column widths are not shrunk to the width of the cell contents), especially for writing out or knitting to pdf.

Having it work for Word would be nice too, but as an aside, writing to Word seems to not preserve the table caption (but I could always add a caption later in Word).

I'm using `huxtable` 4.5.0.

Comment: See `?flextable::width` for how it works in Word. See `?col_width` for why `set_col_width(1:3, c(2,3,1))` has undefined behaviour. Try `set_col_width(1:3, c("2in", "3in", "1in"))`… be prepared to experiment – the `col_width` implementation is not very satisfactory.

Comment: OK, thanks. I did a bit of experimentation (by no means comprehensive), and report results below in an answer. But you are right. `width` and `col_width` are a bit finicky.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the key was to specify `set_wrap(ht) <- TRUE`, then `set_col_width` was responsive for pdf output. But not entirely consistently. When pdf was produced using `quick_pdf`, then a numeric specification like `set_col_width(1:3, c(0.6,0.2,0.2))` failed, and generated an error:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   !
l.108 \end{tabularx}
                    \end{threeparttable} 

Error: Failed to compile C:\Users\staufge\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6p7GhF\file26983e8c25a6.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See file26983e8c25a6.log for more info.
```

The same specification did work when knitting from `rmarkdown`.
Either way, a specification like `set_col_width(1:3, paste0(c(3,2,4),"cm"))` did work well, except that the column widths were very slightly wider (by about 3-4 mm) than the specified width. I though that perhaps playing around with `set_right_padding` (or left) might make the width specifications exact, but it did not appear to have any effect.

Also, it appears that setting `position(ht) <- "center"` (the default) does not explicitly center the table, but rather centers the "table width" specified by `width()`. The table itself appears to be left-justified within that area. So a specification like:

```
width(ht) <- 1
ht <- set_col_width(ht, 1:3, paste0(c(3, 2, 4), "cm"))
```

produces a table that is left-justified within the entire text width, whereas something like:

```
width(ht) <- 0.5
ht <- set_col_width(ht, 1:3, paste0(c(3, 2, 4), "cm"))
```

produces a table that is left-justified within a centered region half the width of the text area (but the table itself is not exactly centered).

In any case,I think I now know how to explicitly set table width, which is what I was after.

Comment: Could you report the failure to compile in github? Thanks (package author)

Comment: OK, I've just posted this on GitHub.